# Can't receive mail from Gmail

Tags: android, gmail, jakarta-mail

I have been trying to receive mail from a gmail account. But I could not do that. I read all questions in Stack Overflow and tried all answers but it didn't work.

Yesterday I found this website : http://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!category-topic/gmail/reading-and-receiving-messages/XD0C4sw9K7U

According to the website; there is no way any more for receiving mail in Gmail.

My first question is; there is too many Java code for receiving mail from a Gmail account. With these codes I can see my mail content on console. Why we cannot receive mail in Android Application? or if we can receive mail in android application. How can we do this?

My second question is: if I cannot receive mail from Gmail account, can I receive my mails from a Hotmail account or another mail account?

Answer (score 0):

try this one code

```
Mail m = new Mail(your email_id), your id password ));
String[] toArr = { send email id };
m.setTo(toArr);
m.setFrom(your email_id);
m.setSubject("Out of subject");
m.setBody("Out Of msg ");
try {
  m.send();
// Log.v("TAg", "send Mail");
} catch (Exception e) {
// Log.e("MailApp", "Could not send email", e);
}
```

mail.java

```
public class Mail extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
    private String _user;
    private String _pass;

    private String[] _to;
    private String _from;

    private String _port;
    private String _sport;

    private String _host;

    private String _subject;
    private String _body;

    private boolean _auth;

    private boolean _debuggable;

    private Multipart _multipart;

    public Mail() {
        _host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // default smtp server
        _port = "465"; // default smtp port
        _sport = "465"; // default socketfactory port

        _user = ""; // username
        _pass = ""; // password
        _from = ""; // email sent from
        _subject = ""; // email subject
        _body = ""; // email body

        _debuggable = false; // debug mode on or off - default off
        _auth = true; // smtp authentication - default on

        _multipart = new MimeMultipart();

        // There is something wrong with MailCap, javamail can not find a
        // handler for the multipart/mixed part, so this bit needs to be added.
        MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap
                .getDefaultCommandMap();
        mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html");
        mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml");
        mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain");
        mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed");
        mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822");
        CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc);
    }

    public Mail(String user, String pass) {
        this();

        _user = user;
        _pass = pass;
    }

    public void setTo(String[] toArr) {
        _to = toArr;
    }

    public void setFrom(String from) {
        _from = from;
    }

    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        _subject = subject;
    }

    /** method will be check email validation **/
    public boolean send() throws Exception {
        Properties props = _setProperties();

        if (!_user.equals("") && !_pass.equals("") && _to.length > 0
                && !_from.equals("") && !_subject.equals("")
                && !_body.equals("")) {
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this);

            MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_from));

            InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[_to.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < _to.length; i++) {
                addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(_to[i]);
            }
            msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);

            msg.setSubject(_subject);
            msg.setSentDate(new Date());

            // setup message body
            BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            messageBodyPart.setText(_body);
            _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            // Put parts in message
            msg.setContent(_multipart);

            // send email
            Transport.send(msg);

            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /** This method(addAttachment) will allow attach the file in mail **/
    public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception {
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);

        _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
    }

    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(_user, _pass);
    }

    private Properties _setProperties() {
        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.put("mail.smtp.host", _host);

        if (_debuggable) {
            props.put("mail.debug", "true");
        }

        if (_auth) {
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        }

        props.put("mail.smtp.port", _port);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", _sport);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

        return props;
    }

    // the getters and setters
    public String getBody() {
        return _body;
    }

    public void setBody(String _body) {
        this._body = _body;
    }

    // more of the getters and setters …..
}
```

and add to

1. `mail.jar`
2. `activation.jar`

Comment: This code is just for sending mail with attachment. I had used this code for sending mail before. I have to receive mail from a gmail or another account.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say whether you had found the code on the JavaMail FAQ.  There's a lot of old and bad code floating around out there on the internet but the code on the FAQ is known to work.  Still, it sounds like you've got code that works on the console so maybe this is an Android specific problem.  It's always hard to know what could be going wrong there since Android isn't Java.  The JavaMail FAQ also has debugging tips, in case you haven't found them.  In particular, a protocol trace might provide the information necessary for others to help you debug the problem.

Comment: I see, after read your comment I read the FAQ very carefully and implement to my Android Project but it didnt work again. I will put my code under this question for debug help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
String SSL_FACTORY = "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory";
Properties pr =  new Properties();
pr.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.class", SSL_FACTORY);
pr.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
pr.setProperty("mail.pop3.port",  "995");
pr.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.port", "995");
pr.put("mail.pop3.host", "pop.gmail.com");
pr.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "pop3");

            try {
                Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(pr, null);
                Store store = session.getStore();
                store.connect("username", "password");
                if(store.isConnected()==true)
                {
                System.out.println("Connection is OK");
                }
//              Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
                Folder inbox = store.getDefaultFolder().getFolder("INBOX");
                inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
                Message messages[] = inbox.getMessages();
                for(Message message:messages) 
                {
//              System.out.println(message.getSentDate());
                message.writeTo(System.out);
                }
```

With this code, I can only move to "store.connect" line. On this line, application stop unexpectedly. So, I couldnt connect even.
Using with mail.jar on Eclipse,Android Project

Comment: If that's your code, you didn't read the FAQ very carefully.  The code in the FAQ is nothing like that.  Also, I'd still like to see the protocol trace.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems reading some gmail messages, so I asked a question regarding that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12955010/1405120). The code in the question can be a good working example for you.

And yes, you can read mails from any server that supports pop3 or imap access. Example for hotmail, just change the host to `pop3.live.com` and protocol to `pop3s`.
Hope that helps!!

Answer (score 0):

http://blogs.wrox.com/files/2013/05/Chapter-8-9781118087299-2.pdf

You will also learn how to use the HTTP protocol to talk to web servers so that you can download text and binary data. The last part of this chapter shows you how to parse XML files to extract the relevant parts of an XML file — a technique that is useful if you are accessing Web services.