# Is this code Correct ? Send Email Via Android

Tags: android, email

I want to know is below code correct ?
I have following code which takes user Name, email address, email subject and email body. Then user clicks submit button:

```
submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO); 
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, nameValue); //nameValue is sender name takes via EditText
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emailValue); //emailValue is sender email address takes via EditText
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subjectValue); //subjectValue is subject of email takes via EditText
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, messageValue); //mesageValue is body of message takes via EditText
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:example@gmail.com"));
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
            startActivity(intent);


        }
    });
```

I have not android phone to test.
In emulator I am getting error below:
[image]

How do I know that above code works fine on phone ??

Comment: you see this link..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821440/cant-receive-mail-from-gmail/9821956#9821956

Comment: see this :[How to send email from your application](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-send-email-your-application)

Comment: I just want to know is my above code or not ? or do i have to set up other mail thing in emulator ?? Help please.

Comment: check this :http://thedevelopersinfo.wordpress.com/2009/10/22/email-sending-in-android/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have no email application installed in your device. Working with this code, you must have email applications installed in your phone.

Comment: I dont have android phone ? cant i test in my emulator ? If yes, how can i ?

Comment: Install [**k9mail**](http://code.google.com/p/k9mail/downloads/list) in your emulator.

Comment: Install k9mail.when i click submit button alertdialog appears saying   `Unsupported Action. The action is not currently supported`   what to do now ?

Answer (score 0):

You might be having to problems with emulator.

1. There might be no email app installed.
2. And if you have email app installed then, you might not be having your id signed in that app, or app might not be handling these intents.

I am also facing same kind of problem with emulator, also not able to sign in into the app. So that Android system can provide users with that application to proceed with.

You might need real phone with id logged in, and application able to handle the intents, to test that thing. You can install the client application on the emulator, or try it on a real phone with an email account logged in with.