# Reading mails sent from GMail

Tags: java, android, gmail, jakarta-mail

I am using JavaMail to read mail in my Android app. I have tried to cover all combinations i.e Mail sent/received on/from Custom Server/Gmail ID/Live ID.

The problem occurs with SOME of the mails sent from GMail WITH Attachment. I am able to receive the attachment, but the content returns `javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart@44f2e698`

Here's the code used to receive and read messages:

```
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imap");

    try {
     /* Create the session and get the store for read the mail. */
     Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
     Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
     store.connect("imap.gmail.com", Username, Password);

     /* Mention the folder name which you want to read. */
     Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
     System.out.println("No of Unread Messages : " + inbox.getUnreadMessageCount());         

     /* Open the inbox using store. */
     inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

     Message messages[] = inbox.getMessages();       
     Log.d("Inbox", "Message Count: "+inbox.getMessageCount());

     for (int i = messages.length - 1 ; i > 0; --i) {
         Log.i("ContentType", "ContentType: "+messages[i].getContentType());

         Object msgContent = messages[i].getContent();

         String content = "";

         /* Check if content is pure text/html or in parts */            
         if (msgContent instanceof Multipart) {

             Multipart multipart = (Multipart) msgContent;

             Log.e("BodyPart", "MultiPartCount: "+multipart.getCount());

             for (int j = 0; j < multipart.getCount(); j++) {

              BodyPart bodyPart = multipart.getBodyPart(j);

              String disposition = bodyPart.getDisposition();

              if (disposition != null && (disposition.equalsIgnoreCase("ATTACHMENT"))) { // BodyPart.ATTACHMENT doesn't work for gmail
                  System.out.println("Mail have some attachment");

                  DataHandler handler = bodyPart.getDataHandler();
                  System.out.println("file name : " + handler.getName());                                 
                }
              else { 
                  System.out.println("Content: "+bodyPart.getContent());
                  content= bodyPart.getContent().toString();
                }
            }
         }
         else                
             content= messages[i].getContent().toString();
```

What I know about the problematic mails:

- `getFrom` also return the name i.e it comes in this format FirstName LastName &ltemailID@gmail.com&gt
- MultiPart contains 2 BodyParts:

  - BodyPart 1 returns the content as `javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart@44f2e698`
  - BodyPart 2 returns the correct name for attachment

Comment: what kind of object does the method bodyPart.getContent() return? String? other custom object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> BodyPart 1 returns the content as
>   javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart@44f2e698

Try calling getBodyPart on the [MimeMultiPart](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMultipart.html#getBodyPart%28int%29)

That probably returns a MimeBodyPart you can call [getContent()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart.html#getContent%28%29) on
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart.html#content

Answer (score 0):

You're probably only handling the simplest case of a text message with attachments.  MIME allows much more.  You need to learn about the difference between multipart/mixed, multipart/alternative, multipart/related, and multipart/signed.  The JavaMail FAQ has more information on handling attachments and the msgshow.java demo program included with the JavaMail download bundle shows how to process messages with nested multiparts.