# Javamail don't read email multipart/related

Tags: jakarta-mail, multipart

i have code:

```
Message[] arrayMessages = folderInbox.getMessages();

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayMessages.length; i++) {
            Message message = arrayMessages[i];
            Address[] fromAddress = message.getFrom();
            String from = fromAddress[0].toString();
            String subject = message.getSubject();
            String sentDate = message.getSentDate().toString();

            String contentType = message.getContentType();
            String messageContent = "";

            // store attachment file name, separated by comma
            String attachFiles = "";

            if (contentType.contains("multipart")) {
                // content may contain attachments
                Multipart multiPart = (Multipart) message.getContent();
                int numberOfParts = multiPart.getCount();
                for (int partCount = 0; partCount < numberOfParts; partCount++) {
                    MimeBodyPart part = (MimeBodyPart) multiPart.getBodyPart(partCount);
                    if (Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(part.getDisposition())) {
                        // this part is attachment
                        String fileName = part.getFileName();
                        attachFiles += fileName + ", ";
                        part.saveFile(saveDirectory + File.separator + fileName);
                    } else {
                        // this part may be the message content
                        messageContent = part.getContent().toString();
                    }
                }

                if (attachFiles.length() > 1) {
                    attachFiles = attachFiles.substring(0, attachFiles.length() - 2);
                }
            }else if (contentType.contains("text/plain")|| contentType.contains("text/html")) {
                Object content = message.getContent();
                if (content != null) {
                    messageContent = content.toString();
                }
            }

            // print out details of each message
            System.out.println("Message #" + (i + 1) + ":");
            System.out.println("\t From: " + from);
            System.out.println("\t Subject: " + subject);
            System.out.println("\t Sent Date: " + sentDate);
            System.out.println("\t Typ wiadomosci: " + contentType);
            System.out.println("\t Message: " + messageContent);
            System.out.println("\t Attachments: " + attachFiles);
            System.out.println("------------------------------------------------");
        }
```

This code get email with attachment, i have problem with getting email type: multipart/related. Instead of messages i have:com.sun.mail.util.BASE64DecoderStream@f61227
or javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart@7612a

Comment: maybe helpful, see my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12955010/reading-mails-sent-from-gmail

Comment: You would probably get more help if you posted an SSCCE (http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

A multipart/related part appears as Java type MimeMultipart.

Comment: I'm not going to give you a tutorial on using MimeMultipart, but you can find plenty of tutorials, documentation, and examples on the JavaMail web site.  You might want to start with the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html).