# getContent() in android gives output as MimeMultiPart, but i actually want email body content as it is

Tags: android, imap, jakarta-mail, mime-types

I am developing an android application, in which I have to fetch emails. For that I have used IMAP service with java I am getting folders, email ids, etc. but not email message body part as it is in EditText widget, I am getting a line like this- `javax.mail.internet.MimeMultiPart@45eb3663`

So how can we solve this problem and can get email message body part as it is (how it was sent) 
I used code like,

```
bodyPart=message[arg2].getContent().toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

If an email has multiple parts (eg an HTML and plain text part or attachments), you get an [javax.mail.internet.MimeMultiPart](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMultipart.html).

When you look at the API documentation, you see that you can use `getCount()` to get a hold of the number of parts and `getBodyPart(int index)` to get a specific part.

You would have to find out which part you are interested in. The following code example grabs all parts and prints the contents:

```
MimeMultiPart multiPart = message[arg2].getContent();
for(int i = 0; i < multiPart.getCount(); i++) {
    Object content = multiPart.getBodyPart(i).getContent();
    System.out.println(content);
}
```

Hope this helps you to understand how emails are received and how to do something with it in Java. The exact use depends on your application, which you need to figure out yourself.

Answer (score 1):

A mail could be plain text, html or Multipart(text + attachments), Multipart Alternative(text + html) etc.
You have to iterate through each BodyPart to know it's type and then get the content accordingly. This javamail FAQ [entry](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#mainbody) could help you.
Also see a similar question of mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12955010/reading-mails-sent-from-gmail).

Answer (score 0):

if you use JavaMail, the code segment may be changed to :

```
String contentType = message.getContentType().toLowerCase(Locale.Canada);
if (contentType.startsWith("multipart/alternative")) {

    // here is data handler part
    DataHandler dataHandler = message.getDataHandler();
    DataSource dataSource = dataHandler.getDataSource();
    if (dataSource instanceof IMAPMultipartDataSource) {
        IMAPMultipartDataSource imapDataSource = (IMAPMultipartDataSource) dataSource;

        int count = imapDataSource.getCount();
                ...
        }
}
```

the idea is to use DataHandler because the message is in the type of IMAPMessage, not in the type of MultiPart directly.